# jQuery hide parent div if child div is empty

Tags: jquery, html, hide, parent

I've looked around and found a lot of questions about this, but none of the solutions work for me. I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="pricetag">
    <div class="price">400</div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">
    <div class="price"></div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">
    <div class="price">250</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to hide the .pricetag where .price doesn't contain anything. 
It can be a lot of different .pricetag's on the same page but I just want to hide the ones with empty .price.

Is this possible with jQuery? I've tried a lot of different scripts but none have worked properly.

Comment: Will each `.pricetag` element only ever have one `.price` element?

Comment: I insert fr. in the beginning and :- at the end of each .pricetag. So if .price has content it is <div class="pricetag">fr.<div class="price">200</div>:-</div>. If .price is empty it is <div class="pricetag">fr.<div class="price"></div>:-</div>

Comment: But you would never have `<div class="pricetag">fr.<div class="price">200</div><div class="price"></div>:-</div>`, right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector and the [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method, assuming the empty `.price` elements will never contain any text nodes (e.g. a new line character):

```
$(".price:empty").parent().hide();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/VDH8C/).

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much! I've only tried using if statements to check if the div is empty. Thanks again. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I'm allowed to do it :)

Comment: Clever way of doing it. I was unaware of the `:empty` selector. Thanks

Comment: @ClydeLobo - You're welcome :) Just be aware that a single space, or new line, or anything else between the start tag and end tag will count as a text node, which means the `:empty` selector will not match it.

Comment: @JamesAllardice : That I am already aware of. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

This jquery code will do it

```
$(function(){
  $(".price").each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=="")
      $(this).parent(".pricetag").hide();
  });
});
```

jsbin example : http://jsbin.com/ovagus

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.price').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text().length == 0) {
    $(this).parent().hide()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mm4pX/1/

You can use `.is(':empty')` to check if div is empty and then make parent div hidden.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$('.price').each(function() {
    if $('.price').is(':empty') $(this).parent().hide()
});​
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate over all the `.price` elements. The `parent` and `hide` methods apply to all elements in the matched set.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Aha thank-you `:)` I was actually reading the post above, cool, cheers for that!

Answer (score 1):

try this jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    $('div.pricetag').each(function(key, value)
    {
        if(!$('div.price', value).html()) $(value).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:empty` selector does not select a element if it contains whitespaces. If that is a problem then you can trim the element from whitespaces:

```
function isEmpty(element){
  return !$.trim(element.html())
}

$(".box").each(function() {
  var box = $(this);
  var body = box.find(".box-body");

  if(isEmpty(body)) {
    console.log("EMPTY");
    box.hide();
  } 
});
```

http://codepen.io/DanAndreasson/pen/jWpLgM