# Hide parent element if no elements exist in child element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

See the following markup:

```html
<div class="careersIntegration__listing" id="careers-listing">
  
  <div class="careersIntegration__accordion">
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-header">
      <span class="careersIntegration__accordion-dept">Sales</span>
    </div>
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-jobs" data-dept="sales"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="careersIntegration__accordion">
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-header">
      <span class="careersIntegration__accordion-dept">Customer Success</span>
    </div>
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-jobs" data-dept="customer-success">
      <figure class="careerCard" data-dept="customer-success">Job</figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I'm trying to hide `.careersIntegration__accordion`'s which have `.careersIntegration__accordion-jobs` elements that have no children.

To simplify, if `.careersIntegration__accordion-jobs` has no children, hide the parent `.careersIntegration__accordion` element.

I've seen examples on existing SO posts (see this one), but cannot get the approach to work in my instance. See posts below which I have tried:

- [jquery if div id has children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526873/jquery-if-div-id-has-children)
- [jQuery hide parent div if child div is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290432/jquery-hide-parent-div-if-child-div-is-empty)
- [css hide div if div has no child with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939335/css-hide-div-if-div-has-no-child-with-class)

With my current approach below, the `else` statement is executed, unsure why?

```js
$(".careersIntegration__accordion").each(function(){
  if( $(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs").length == 0 ){
    $(this).parent().hide();
  } else{
    console.log('has children');
  }
});
```

Comment: `.children(selector)` = `.children().filter(selector)`, not `.find(">" + selector).children()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your assumption

`$(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs")`

doesn't return the children of elements using the CSS class `careersIntegration__accordion-jobs`. In fact it only returns the actual elements using this CSS class. If you want to have it's children you need to append another call to `.children()`.

For example:

```js
$(".careersIntegration__accordion").each(function() {
  if ($(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs").children().length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    console.log('has children');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="careersIntegration__listing">

  <!-- this should be hidden -->
  <div class="careersIntegration__accordion">
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-header">
      <span class="careersIntegration__accordion-dept">Sales</span>
    </div>
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-jobs"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- this should not be hidden -->
  <div class="careersIntegration__accordion">
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-header">
      <span class="careersIntegration__accordion-dept">Tech</span>
    </div>
    <div class="careersIntegration__accordion-jobs">
      <div>item</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi, using `.$(this).parent().hide();` hides the `. careersIntegration__listing` `div`. I've tried it with `.$(this).hide();`, so that it targets the `.careersIntegration__accordion` `div` instead. But, this didn't work for me either, it hid all of the `.careersIntegration__accordion` `div`'s

Comment: Sorry my bad - I didn't test that part of your code as I assumed it's correct. I just corrected the snippet in my answer to use `$(this).hide();` instead and it seems to work as only the Sales div disappears. Still no luck?

Comment: Hmm, I have copied your `js` exactly, but in my instance, it hides all of the divs. See image here: https://i.imgur.com/lcK05RS.png. From the image you can see that one `.careersIntegration__accordion-jobs` has child elements, and one doesn't, but both of them are being targeted and hidden by the `js`

Comment: The inline styles on `.careersIntegration__accordion` are set by the `hide()` function. I have no inline or other css set on `.careersIntegration__accordion`

Comment: Can you post your exact code as a working snippet to your question?

Comment: No major changes from previous version, but done, updated question.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? What do you see if you put a `console.log($(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs")[0],$(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs")[0].children.length);` inside the `.each()` block?

Comment: I'm on jQuery version `3.6.0` and here is an image which shows the `console.log` requested: https://i.imgur.com/gUHsYli.png

Comment: I'm running out of ideas Freddy. I tried replicating your scenario by using 10 `<figure>` elements too and it correctly reports that there are 10 children. What is inside of each of those elements?

Comment: My apologies, I had a `fetch()` function running in which these `.careerCards` were being sorted into their categories. Your reply got me thinking that it may be returning `0` as it's running at the wrong time, so I moved your JS into my fetch and it started to work. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Ah there lies the rub. I'm glad I could help and you got it sorted now! =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `html()` to get the information you need and then check if it's equal to an empty string:

```
$(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs").html() === ''
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: You'll need to consider whitespace, so make sure you trim() before comparing

Answer (score 0):

Because `$(this).children(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs").length` just counts the elements with the class `careersIntegration__accordion-jobs` - but you want to inspect the children of these elements.

The following code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".careersIntegration__accordion .careersIntegration__accordion-jobs").each(function(){
  console.log("children().length="+$(this).children().length);
    if( $(this).children().length == 0 ){
      $(this).hide();
      console.log('no children');
    } else{
      console.log('has children');
    }
  });
});
```

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/czs0uya5/

Comment: Hi, using `if( $(this).find(".careersIntegration__accordion-jobs div").length == 0 ){` hides all of my `.careersIntegration__accordion` sections

Comment: Try `$(this).hide();` instead of `$(this).parent().hide();`

Comment: With the above, it hides all of my '. careersIntegration__accordion` `divs`

Comment: Is your jQuery code placed inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...<here>...});`?

Comment: Yup. In addition to this, I have no console errors also

Comment: I updated my solution. It should work now.